# VBA Excel Worksheet_Change Problema

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo un problema al momento de estar codificando con `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Debido a que son tantas las celdas que hacen cambios y que a su vez son triggers unas de otras, que ha llegado el momento en que excel me dice `"the procedure is too large"`,

¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Este es un solo ejemplo del código pero al menos son 1000 celdas que activan algo, y la condición es que no se puede hacer en diferentes hojas, todo debe suceder en la misma.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

If Target.Address = "$C$3" Then
    If Range("C3") = "Persona Moral" Then
    Range("6:14,293:323,519:536").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("4:5,15:45,144:152,478:494").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = False
    Else
    If Range("C3") = "Persona Física" Then
    Range("6:10,293:294,297:297,300:323,330:330,338:339,519:532").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("4:5,11:45,144:152,478:494").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = False
    Else
    If Range("C3") = "Fideicomiso" Then
    Range("11:14,533:534,536:536").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("4:10,15:532,535:535").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = True
        Else
    If Range("C3") = "" Then
    Rows("4:599").Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = False
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: @gbianchi Hola!, me gustaría saber como evitar el problema de "procedure too large", ya que si es demasiado código el que llevará está hoja y el 95% de ellos se activan mediante el evento change, saludos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu procedimiento es tan largo que vba no lo puede procesar.

lo que tenes que hacer es reducir el codigo sacando todo lo que sea repetitivo o no tenga sentido (si fue armado automaticamente)

como ejemplo:

```
If Range("C3") = "Persona Moral" Then
    Range("6:14,293:323,519:536").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("4:5,15:45,144:152,478:494").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = False
    Else
    If Range("C3") = "Persona Física" Then
    Range("6:10,293:294,297:297,300:323,330:330,338:339,519:532").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Range("4:5,11:45,144:152,478:494").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Worksheets("Representantes Legales").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes").Visible = False
    Else
```

podria traducirse a algo asi:

```
If Range("C3") = "Persona Moral" Then
   //ocultar cosas
   Ocultar("6:14,293:323,519:536",true,"4:5,15:45,144:152,478:494",false,"Representantes Legales",true,"Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes",false)
Else
   If Range("C3") = "Persona Física" Then
      Ocultar("6:10,293:294,297:297,300:323,330:330,338:339,519:532",false,"4:5,11:45,144:152,478:494",true,"Representantes Legales",false,"Fideicomisarios-Fideicomitentes",true)

Sub Ocultar(a,b,c,d, etc...)
   Range(a).EntireRow.Hidden = b
   Range(c).EntireRow.Hidden = d
   ...
end sub
```

Yo tambien reemplazaria el `if` kilometrico por un `select case`